# Pandas slice rolling by day

Tags: python, pandas, slice

i'm scratiching my head for a pandas slicing problem.
I have a dataframe with a date time column and a time date index (every 15 minutes), i want to create a new column with the same frequency (15min) that contains the max value of another column in the previous day (it will be the same value for each row within the same day).

My dataframe is call klines i know that i can get the date of each row with

```
klines['date']=klines['timedate'].dt.date
```

I know I can create a timedelta with timedelta function but I can't figure out how to use the timedate object

I was hoping that something like

```
klines['max_prev_day']=klines[klines['Close time'].dt.date+dt.timedelta(days = -1):klines['Close time'].dt.date]['value_to_look'].max()
```

But i'm getting a loc error

```
 raise InvalidIndexError(key)
```

Any clever input is wellcome !

Comment: could you show a quick couple of rows of your dataframe.  I would love to know the type and format of date time and time date index

Comment: it's a simple financial data datetime index and high low open close volume. the intention is to generate the pivot point levels for the previous day

Comment: '                            open    high  ...  max_min_slope  Label
time                                      ...                      
2015-01-07 10:45:00-05:00  14.85  14.880  ...       0.000920      1
2015-01-07 11:00:00-05:00  14.87  14.945  ...       0.000920      1
2015-01-07 11:15:00-05:00  14.90  14.920  ...       0.000919      1
2015-01-07 11:30:00-05:00  14.90  14.940  ...       0.000918      1
2015-01-07 11:45:00-05:00  14.93  14.990  ...       0.000917      1'